# Loading block in layout issue

Tags: layout, xml

This is the url `....customer/address/new/`. This is the code from the layout:

```
<customer_address_new>
        <reference name="root"> 
           <block type="core/template" name="headertext" template="customer/address/header_address.phtml" />
        </reference>
</customer_address_new>
```

This is a code from 2column-left.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('headertext')
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $module = $request->getModuleName();
    $controller = $request->getControllerName();
    $action = $request->getActionName();
?>
```

The result of a var_dump for `$module` is : **customer**

The result of a var_dump for `$controller` is : **address**

The result of a var_dump for `$action` is : **form**

I tried every combination of creating my xml.  These are the combination

```
<customer_address_new>
<customer_address_form>
<customer_address_index>
```

neither of them are not working. What am I missing ?

Comment: What block are you trying to create on this page?

Comment: Also add this `Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());` to your 2column-left.phtml this will give you the layout handles that are being used

Comment: It shows me this: <customer_address_form>. But still doesn't work

Comment: If I change the template path  it works. Weird. Can you help me with this ?:)

Answer (score 1):

Ok From what i understand you only want your block to appear on the url `customer/address/new/` You should be able to add your block in your `local.xml` via the following:

```
<customer_address_form>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="headertext" before="-" template="customer/address/header_address.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_address_form>
```

Notice on the block i have the attribute `before="-"` this basically states that we want this block to be before all others.

In the template `customer/address/header_address.phtml` i have just added the following text: `HELLO THIS IS MY BLOCK!`.

You should get the following output:

[image]